# Reassign a namespace in the same dev org

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

Can you reassign the namespace in a developer org to another package?

I currently have a manage package and in that package I've assigned my namespace. I created a Beta version for now.

Ultimately I want to keep using the namespace but use an up to date code.

Answer (score 0):

**Warning. It only works if you have a beta package. If you release the package then you will not be able to**

Turns out that you can't find any information online about this but You can!

My beta package needed to be deprecated and I manage to delete the package entirely from the dev org. - Keep in mind that when you delete the package it doesn't remove the objects and components from that org so you will have to go back into the org and manually delete everything. This is probably the only hassle.

I then created a new package. reassigned the namespace to this new package and created a release version from there.

I've read some reviews that some people say you can but you have to uninstall from all your customers. Deprecate every version and it may work but I can't confirm that.